# How to arrange a Button inside of a stack for various screen size devices in Flutter Programming Language? ( FLUTTER )

Tags: flutter, stack, containers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hI4R.png)
Above is the image of a button that i'm trying to arrange in a screen.

### I'm new to the flutter and i am trying to arrange a button on the display with variable screen sizes can anybody help me please. here is my container which is inside of a stack.

```
[new Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 120.0, left: 50.0),
               // margin: EdgeInsets.fromWindowPadding(),
                child: new RaisedButton(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                  child: new Text(
                    'Sponsor A Run',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: displayWidth(context) * 0.06,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  color: isButtonPressed
                      ? Colors.orange
                      : Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.4),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isButtonPressed = !isButtonPressed;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we can use the MediaQuery.of(context).size.height and MediaQuery.of(context).size.width to get the data of the screen sizes, and we can just multiply a fraction to it to place the widgets

```dart
class ClassName extends StatelessWidget {
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final windowHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final windowWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return ...(
       child : Container(margin : EdgeInsets.only( top : windowHeight * 0.3, left : windowWidth * 0.2) //this will give the container the margin top of 30% the height in all devices, and we can do the same for the width property also
);
```

You can also subtract the padding and the previous widget's height to align then even better :)